# make a row 100% inside a div with height: auto

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I have a div with height: auto. Inside there is a div with height: 100% but it doesn't work. How it is possible to make it work without making a table or giving an exact height in px? I'm making a navbar in bootstrap and as the height of the whole navbar changed I expected my nav also will change it's height.

Here is a code:
http://www.bootply.com/OrL4quEWML

I need my active tab has a border in the very bottom of header.

Comment: "I have a div with height: auto. Inside there is a div with height: 100%" <- 100% to which div?

Comment: The `height: 100%` has to be relevant to something. In other words it's parent must have a height so the child can have a height that is 100% of it.

Comment: Alan is right, something needs an actual height, either through css or actual content. There can be positioning issues as well. Simplify your example to just the necessary parts stackoverflow may help more.